# Run cachewarmer on startup

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application and have a CacheWarmerService in the service container. Currently I just use an in memory cache, but I need it to be run when the application starts up.

However, I'm in doubt on how to do it. My CacheWarmerService has some services that needs to be injected in the constructor. Can I do that from the Startup.cs class, or where should this be placed?

It needs to be run every time it starts.

Comment: I assume your services just need database stuff (`DbContext`) and no HttpContext right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could also create your own nice and clean extension method like `app.UseCacheWarmer()` that you could then call from `Startup.Configure()`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    ... logging, exceptions, etc

    app.UseCacheWarmer();

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Inside that method you can use `app.ApplicationServices` to access to the DI container (the `IServiceProvider`) and get instances of the services that you need.

```
public static class CacheWarmerExtensions
{
    public static void UseCacheWarmer(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        var cacheWarmer = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<CacheWarmerService>();
        cacheWarmer.WarmCache();
    }
}
```

Comment: Both answers works great, but I really like this approach as it keeps the Startup-file clean.

Comment: The `Use` pattern is generally associated with adding middleware to the request pipeline, not to initialize services.

Comment: You could always find an alternate name for it like `app.InitCache()` if in your app you want to be strict about the convention `app.UseXYZ()` being just with middleware. The point is having an extension method so adding the cache service on any web app is as simple as possible.

Answer (score 8):

You can inject your service (and any other service) in the `Configure` method of `Startup`.

The only required parameter in this method is `IApplicationBuilder`, any other parameters will be injected from DI if they've been configured in `ConfigureServices`.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, CacheWarmerService cache)
{
    cache.Initialize();  // or whatever you call it

    ...

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: In asp.net core 2.1 you can no longer inject parameters in the Configure method

Comment: I must have done something wrong initially since I was getting an exception and now I just tried it again it's working as you described. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: I think they have to be registered with a singleton lifetime scope for it to work.

Comment: @fml The Cache does yeah, but if you need scoped services to populate the cache you can just create a scope context with this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceproviderserviceextensions.createscope?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

Not sure if this is what you were alluding to or not but just figured I would in case

Answer (score 2):

If someone using Daniels method, and if using scoped services like EF data context inside the cachewarm service, you will get below error.

```
'Cannot resolve 'ICacheWarmerService' from root provider because it requires scoped service 'dbContext'.'
```

For this you can create scope and use your cached method.

```
public static void UseCacheWarmer(this IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
    {
        var cacheWarmer = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ICacheWarmerService>();
        cacheWarmer.WarmCache();
     }

     //// var cacheWarmer = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ICacheWarmerService>();
     //// cacheWarmer.WarmCache();
}
```